# Laravel socialite URL error 6: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am trying to use Laravel Socialite with version 9, I got an error when using Laravel Socialite with a google account, but in local it work well, and here is the error message:

`"cURL error 6: getaddrinfo() thread failed to start (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"`

and here is code:

```
public function redirectToGoogle()
    {
        // $error = 'dafasdfasdfas';
        // return redirect()->route('backpack.auth.login')->with('error','Not allow ');
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }
        
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handleGoogleCallback()

    {   // Try to exception
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user(); // google gmail

            if (explode("@", $user->email)[1] != 'global-mobility-service.com'){
                return redirect()->route('backpack.auth.login')->with('error','Email Not Allow');
            }

            $finduser = User::where('email', '=', $user->email)->first();
       
            if(isset($finduser) == true){
       
                $updateUser = User::where('email', '=', $user->email)->update([
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'google_id'=> $user->id,
                ]);

                Auth::login($finduser);
      
                return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
       
            }else{
                $newUser = User::create([
                    'name' => $user->name,
                    'email' => $user->email,
                    'google_id'=> $user->id,
                    'password' => encrypt('123456')
                ]);

                $newUser->assignRole(2);

                Auth::login($newUser);
      
                return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
            }
      
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Appreciate you guys for helping me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> but in local it work well

Based on this I am assuming you are deploying your code *somewhere* and that is where you are having this issue. Therefore, I think you will want to check if you can reach https://www.googleapis.com from where ever you have deployed your code to. Check any firewall or network settings that might be preventing outside calls.

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes sure, I am trying to deploy my application with docker but, I work well before for the last version.